# How to add within a .each code block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have 8 transactions in a ruby array (@transactions) and each transaction has a number value associated with them that I need to add to get one number, the sum of each transaction's number. How can I use a code block to add the numbers together? Is a code block the best way to iterate through to get a total?

```
@transactions.each do | t |

  # ??

end
```

Comment: In Ruby, as in many other things, there are many "best" ways, each depending on the context.

Comment: Given a transaction `t`, how do you access your "number value"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby on rails has a [`sum`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) function:

```
@transactions.sum { |t| t.number_value }
```

or if you want additional brevity

```
@transactions.sum(:number_value)
```

Comment: Note that the second way in this answer is only made available by `Ruby on Rails` itself, not the ruby programming language.  But it sounds like you're using Rails so that should be fine :)  Oh I guess you did mention "Rails" at the beginning of the answer :p

Comment: In Rails the latter would certainly be superior -- it pushes the sum to the database and returns just the required value. Much faster and more simple.

Answer (score 2):

Do as below Using [`Enumerable#reduce`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce):

```
@transactions.reduce(0) { |sum,ob| sum + ob.number_val }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try below code. Although this question might have been answered long before. You should once google the question before you post it.

```
@transaction.inject(0){|sum,x| sum + x.number_value }
```

Comment: diff between `reduce` and `inject` ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit : They are the same. Different names for the same method.

Comment: Actually this won't work; without the `0` parameter like in Arup's answer, it will try to set the initial value of `sum=@transaction[0]` which is not necessarily a number.

Comment: @Matt : I just tried it out. Its working without the initialising the sum first.

Comment: I did too: `trans = [ "1", "2", "3" ]` `trans.inject{|sum,x| sum+x.to_i}` `=> TypeError: can't convert Fixnum into String` What is your example?

Comment: I used integers for example. a = [1,2,3,4,5] a.inject{|s,x| s + x }=>15

Comment: That's because `a[0]` *is* a number, so of course it will work. `@transaction[0]` may not be, and probably isn't.